# integrate payments on Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7, in-app-purchase

Is there a way to integrate payments into a Windows Phone 7.5 application like the native In App Purchasing in Windows Phone 8?

I've searched around and read about someone that integrated PayPal redirecting to website using browserControl. But it seems that this can prevent the certification of the app on Windows Phone Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not prohibited.
There is no native In-app purchasing for WP7 apps, so you can use any other way.

Also, if your app is running on WP8 device you can use Reflection to reach InAP libraries

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside+Windows+Phone/Inside-Windows-Phone-45--Adding-In-App-Purchase-as-a-light-up-feature-to-your-Windows-Phone-7-Games

---

[App policies for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184841%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> **2.1.2** If your app includes in-app billing functionality but does not use the Microsoft in-app purchase API provided by Windows Phone, the
>   following requirement applies:
>
> Unless you have a pre-existing billing
>   relationship with the user, your app may not require the user to
>   provide payment information, within the app experience, to activate,
>   unlock, or extend usage of the app. If you do not have a pre-existing
>   billing relationship with the user, payment and personal account
>   information must be collected outside of the app experience via a
>   secure HTTPS website or as a hosted control within the app where the
>   user can verify the URL and HTTPS security.